# Adding the date to 5 text boxes but increasing them by X amount of days

Tags: javascript

Im trying to update 5 text fields with X amount of days in the future
text1, text2 and text3 need to be forward by 29 days and showing the same date
text4 and text5 need to be 2 days beyond the other

What is currently happening is text1 is showing todays date, text2-4 are showing 29 days in the future and text5 is showing 2 days beyond the others

```
var current_date = new Date();
var number_of_dateBoxes = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= number_of_dateBoxes; i++){
    $w('#text'+ i).text = current_date.toLocaleDateString();
    if (i==1) {
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+29);
    }
    else if (i==2 || i==3) {
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()-29);
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+29);
    }
    else if (i==4 || i==5) {
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()-29);
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+31);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't know what `$w` is but I believe it's from some library you use and since you wrote somethings change it means it works so it doesn't matter.

You have to put your `current_date` declaration inside the loop and `$w('#text'+ i).text` at the end of the loop. Also remove some unneeded lines and arrange them like  :

```
var number_of_dateBoxes = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= number_of_dateBoxes; i++){
    var current_date = new Date();
    if (i==1 || i==2 || i==3) {
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+29);
    }
    else if (i==4 || i==5) {
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+31);
    }
    $w('#text'+ i).text = current_date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```